# Assigning result from createObjectURL to image fails to load resource on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I'm capturing a picture from the camera as follows:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

I bind to the change event of the input.

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('change',  processFile);
```

When a picture is made (or selected from the library) the processFile function is called:

```
processFile = function (e) {
    var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imageUrl;
}
```

This works fine for most browsers, but on mobile Safari (10.1) I get the following exception:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (blob:https://example.com/29ce6a7c-c266-4b39-8de2-9ec61cc38455, line 0)
```

I debugged and it goes wrong when I assign the imageUrl (blob:) to the src property of the img object.

I reproduced this in a small codepen as well:

https://codepen.io/geersch/pen/rKrwEN

Only fails on iOS 10.1 for me. Also tested with iOS 10.3.2 and there it works fine. Anybody knows what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the iPad device that was having the issue was running on iOS 10.1 beta 1, which more than likely is the cause of the issue.